# How to remove View/edit option of a node in admin menu?

Tags: 7, nodes

Drupal 7 node edit and view are showing in admin menu. How do I show it under node title?

Actually when the node is loading, the view edit options of the node is showing under the node title but when fully loaded, the view/edit options of that node is showing in the admin menu.
When I checked it with the firebug, it's under admin menu css.

How do I show the view/edit options under the node title?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Configuration -> Administration -> Administration Menu.
2. Under System Tweaks, **uncheck** *Move local tasks into menu*.
3. Flush the cache and clear browser cache.